# How to encrypt jwt token on the client app before storing it in the local storage

Tags: javascript, frontend

Here is an idea.

I have a web app with GraphQL API on the backend and React client on the front.
When a user enters a username and password server returns access and a refresh token. Since I don't want (or cannot) store tokens in cookies, I want to store them in local storage (persisted storage).
Storing tokens in local storage is a bad practice since they can be stolen and used to gain access to the app. But if a token is encrypted with a secret key known only to this particular client then it can be safely stored in local storage. And even token is stolen it will be unuseful on the server side. The client should decrypt the token before sending it to the server. The secret key must be unique and persistent for each client, and shouldn't be stored in the browser, but read by javascript and constructed from device specifics: browser name, browser version, device name, etc (browser fingerprinting).

My question is - can someone looking into client javascript code see how the secret key is constructed, and then read from the browser the same data and decrypt the token?
What techniques can we use on the front end to hide our logic implementation?

Comment: if the token was stolen, all the "device specifics" you mentioned can be mimicked, try copying a request from console\network as curl and see

Answer (score 1):

> can someone looking into client javascript code see how the secret key is constructed, and then read from the browser the same data and decrypt the token?

Yes.

> What techniques can we use on the front end to hide our logic implementation?

None.

---

If encrypted data and the key (or the information needed to reconstruct the key) to decrypt it are ever in the same place then the data is not secure in that moment.